# Passing a callback via an Iframe postMessage?

Tags: javascript, iframe, postmessage

I want to allow an external iframe to call a function available on the parent site.
The catch is that I need the child to get the result (or error) of that operation and do something based on the result.
Since it's not possible to pass callback functions via postMessages, is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use postMessage again.

1. Child document calls `postMessage` on the parent document with a request to do the operation.
2. A message event handler in the parent document is triggered by that message, which generates a result and then calls `postMessage` on the child document with the result (which could be encoded as JSON if the result is complex)
3. A message event handler in the child document gets the response and deals with it

Comment: And what if this function is async? Let's say the child wants to wait for the parent response before the next call?

Comment: "And what if this function is async?" — postMessage communication is asynchronous anyway.

Comment: "Let's say the child wants to wait for the parent response before the next call?" — Then don't make the next call until Step 3.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it, eventually:
When a child sends a message to the parent I:
A. Attach a unique key to the payload.
B. Create a promise.
Then, when the operation is done on the parent side, it sends a message back with the result + the key.
When the parent sends the response, I use the key to resolve the correct promise.